# Angular 4 with IE11 - Router Outlet and Ng If Problems

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular4-router

This problem happens in IE11 alone. ( It works perfectly on Chrome, Edge, Firefox)

1) Router-outlet contents keeps on repeating even though we navigate to different page in a Angular Application.

2) Ng If is not honored, so if a right caret icon of drop down component is clicked we show the list of probable items, however if we click on the caret icon again, the items are rendered beneath again so the drop down values section keeps on repeating again and again.
We have a check based on Ng-If that if dropdownIsAlreadyShown then don't create the dom again, but its not respected. Same code works on other browsers.

I have seen this kind of questions all over stack overflow but no one has given answer on it. The IE version is 11.1029.15063.0

Any help appreciated? Please don't provide answers like clearing cache, Machine restarts and all.

Comment: If you're using @angular/cli, have you uncommented all the necessary shims?

Comment: This feels like that there are errors which stops the normal rendering of the page. What do you see in your browser's console while using the app? Are you sure there are no any errors?

Comment: @pixelbits . 

I have provided all these pollyfils.
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/object';

Comment: @ForestG Good point. I have noticed some errors while page load and all, but can it be because of it? There are some errors related to calc usage, which is happening before coming to this page.

Comment: I think, that your specific problems (double rendering, etc.) is happening because your program has runtime errors and stops working. (some of your js files continues to function, some of them run on errors, the result is a complete mess). You have to fix your problems, whatever they are in the console, and then, your page will work again.

Comment: @ForestG Your pointers are very much appreciated. However, I just debugged on my local and found that there are no errors in the console of IE 11. Only Info logs and this time as well same problem. NgIf doesn't work even though javascript behind the scenes is toggling between false/true. So, dropdown values keeps on adding up in the DOM. As I mentioned same code works in all other browsers too.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  Did you find a resolution?